# jbutton text color issue at diffrent pc

Tags: java, jbutton

i made a GUI with buttons that can be disabled. if the buttons are getting disabled the text color gets changed to grey. on my computer everything works fine, but i tried it on a diffrent one (both have win 7. the other computer (where the error happens) has a touchscreen, dont know if this could cause the problem and on my computer i have java 6 on the problem computer java 7) and there, the text color stays white..!
i have no idea what to do.
here some code, perhaps it helps (overriden setEnabled-method):

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean b)
{
    super.setEnabled(b);
    if(!this.isEnabled()){
        String text = "";
        if(!this.getText().contains("<html>")){
            text = "<html><font color=\"#797C88\">" + this.getText() + "</font></html>";
        }
        else{
            text = this.getText().replaceAll("#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}", "#797C88");
        }

        this.setText(text);
    }
    else{
        String text = "";
        if(!this.getText().contains("<html>")){
            text = "<html><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + this.getText() + "</font></html>";
        }
        else{
            text = this.getText().replaceAll("#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}", "#FFFFFF");
        }

        this.setText(text);
    }
}
```

this is the custom look and feel (all the images are working well, on the other pc, so i think there should be no error in the look and feel...):

```
<style id="button">
    <!-- Shift the text one pixel when pressed -->
    <property key="Button.textShiftOffset" type="integer" value="2" />
    <state>
        <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button_normal.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10" />
        <font name="Dialog" size="12" />
    </state>
    <state value="PRESSED">
        <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button_normal_pressed.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10" />
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="button" type="region" key="Button" />
```

as i said, on my computer this code works fine. on the other one not.
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you are not victim of the subtle ways greys and whites are shown on different screens? Can you temporarily switch to something more obvious (like green or red) and see if it works?

Comment: i found the problem. its the java version. the 7th doesnt work. but i have no idea why...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Bugreport](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4783068) since Java 7 components with HTML text gray out the text when disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing font colour by using the code:

```
text = "<html><font color=\"#797C88\">" + this.getText() + "</font></html>";
```

and

```
text = this.getText().replaceAll("#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}", "#797C88");
```

you should probably use:

```
this.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
```

And to change the text to white:

```
this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Possibly better as a comment, as this answer doesn't actually solve the issue. But good point all the same.

Comment: i found the problem. its the java version. the 7th doesnt work. but i have no idea why...